# Solution to a system of differential equations expressed in terms of a vector cross product

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, cross-product

I want to possibly analytically solve the following system of differential equations.

$$ X'(t) =  \left\langle \frac{3}{4}, \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} \sin(t) , \frac{-\sqrt3}{4}\cos (t) \right\rangle \times X(t) $$

where $X(0) = \left\langle \frac{\sqrt3}{2}, 0, -\frac{1}{2} \right\rangle $ and the '$\times$' denotes the vector cross product.

I know how to solve a system of differential equations when it is of the form $X' = AX$ where $A$ is some $3 \times 3$ matrix. One finds the eigen values of the matrix $A$ and proceed from there as usual. Is it possible to express the above problem in that form?. Any hints on how I should proceed?

Comment: yes, try and express the cross product with matrix multiplication, I am sure there exist answers on here who show you how to do that but I don't remember where they are.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I should have seen this before. You can actually express a cross product as the product of a skew symmetric matrix and a vector. this solves my problem.

Comment: Many things in life get much easier once you find a matrix for them to do their thing.